# Do duplicate title tags with and without www hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects

For my website, I own `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`.

(Currently, `http://example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com`.)

I recently had an audit of my website and it reported that `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` are duplicate title tags. **Of course they are** - because one redirects to the other!

**Does this really hurt my SEO??**

Comment: If you are sure that one redirects to the other properly, then it is a failing of whatever tool you used. I would not worry about it. You buy yourself some insurance by setting a preference for www in Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Cool. I don't think I quite understand your last sentence, though....

Comment: Also, along the same lines, does `https://example.com/page` and `https://example.com/page/` hurt SEO?

Comment: Ooopppsss a typo! In Google Webmaster Tools you can specify that you prefer www.example.com to be displayed in the SERPs rather than example.com. Now I know this sounds unrelated, but this option is like telling Google to in effect ignore example.com and accept www.example.com. It is not explicit, but that was half of the original intent of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a proper 301 redirect setup from non-www to www like you said, then no you will not see any negative impact from those 'duplicate' title tags. They aren't duplicate because the first page doesn't exist, it has been 301'd to your www version. I would say whoever did the audit used an automated tool without actually looking at your site.

As to your comment, using or not using a trailing slash `/` will not change any SEO aspects of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how that page can hurt your SEO process if that do not exist in web? Right. hen you have made a proper redirect from blog page to domain, then there should not be any issue of duplicacy even if they have same content or titles.